# Gtk notebook - store/restore detached tabs

Tags: c++, tabs, gtk, gtkmm, gtk2

i want to store the settings for tabs which were detached into another Notebook somehow in a file, so that i can restore them when i close/open the program (written in C++). I couldn't find any settings/properties which gives or let me set the position/order of detached tabs.

Can anyone tell me if there even exists that kind of feature in gtkmm 2.4 or how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Greetings
Burak

Answer (score 1):

Use the notebook's `get_nth_page()` method to retrieve the position of each tab when you want to save the state in a file. Then when you open the program next time, start with an empty notebook, read the file and add all the tabs according to the the data that you saved there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I managed to store the children somehow, however not with your solution and it stores only the original Tabs with their positions. The problem is, that there is a wrapper class for the gtk notebook widget in my code and it seems i can't access the gtk methods that easily. Guess i'll have to find out first of all how to Access the gtk methods...Thanks anyways. Greetings